# Удаление\добавление пробелов

Tags: c++, строки

Вопрос такой : можно ли сделать ручной ввод  для подобных заданий через cin ?  Через обычный cin не получается ни добавить, ни удалить пробелы - выводит до первого пробела. То есть для подобных заданий нельзя использовать обычный cin, ибо будет выводить до первого пробела?(не getline и подобное)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include  <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    setlocale(0, "rus");
    char nach1[] = "Its me      Dio ";
    char con1[50];
    int jj = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(nach1 - 1); i++)
    {
        if (nach1[i] == ' ' && nach1[i + 1] == ' ')continue;
        con1[jj] = nach1[i], jj++;
    }

    con1[jj] = 0;

    char* vr = con1;
    if (con1[0] == ' ')vr++;

    cout << vr << endl << endl;
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: А что, `getline` уже с `cin` не работает? (*невозможно использовать обычный cin* - это как?)

Comment: @Harry Только сin. Без getline и подобного. И да, я знаю, что работает. Но интересует можно ли как-то без этого.

Comment: Ну переопределите оператор `>>`, если вы подразумеваете именно его...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вас интересует поведение [оператора](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator-free/) чтения C-строк из потока. В справке написано:

> Extracts characters from is and stores them in s as a c-string,
>   **stopping as soon as either a whitespace character is encountered** or
>   (width()-1) characters have been extracted (if width is not zero). A
>   null character (charT()) is automatically appended to the written
>   sequence. The function then resets width to zero.

Другими словами, читать он будет только до того символа, для которого [`isspace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/) вернет `true`. 
[Оператор](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%3E%3E/) чтения `std::string` из потока ведет себя аналогично:

> This function overloads operator>> to behave as described in
>   istream::operator>> for c-strings, but applied to string objects.

---

Но это ведь C++. Любую проблему можно решить при помощи <strike>макросов и шаблонов</strike> собственных классов и перегрузки операторов:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Line{
    std::string _string;
public:
    Line(const std::string &string = std::string()):
        _string(string)
    {}
    operator std::string() const{
        return _string;
    }
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Line &line);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Line &line);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Line &line){
    std::getline(is, line._string);
    return is;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Line &line){
    os << line._string;
    return os;
}

int main(){
    Line name;
    std::cout << "What is your name? "; //Chandler Bing
    std::cin >> name;
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n"; //Hello, Chandler Bing!
}
```